# Validate URL exactly

Tags: iphone, regex, url-validation

i have strucked in validating URL to send to service in my code,can any one give me regular expression for validating URL that should start with **http://** and should ends with **.com** , **.org** ,**.net** ,**.edu** ,**.in** some other common endings in the url.i have searched many but i dint get accurately for this type regular expression.Please help me in this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this method...

```
  - (BOOL) urlIsValiad: (NSString *) url 
 {
    NSString *regex = 
    @"((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
   /// OR use this 
   ///NSString *regex = "(http|ftp|https)://[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]* [\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?";
    NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"URL is valid!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");
    }

    return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];
}
```

Comment: @iPhoneNewBle try this method and also use regex optional this code NSString *regex = "(http|ftp|https)://[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]* [\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?"; i hope this help you.. :)

Comment: i got it with the first reg exp only.once again thanks alot for quick help.

Comment: hi @Paras Joshi, can u give reg exp for "http://xcode.blogspot.in/" type of url?the above reg exp is not validating this.please help me in this?

Comment: hey here your this link not found the page dude so this happen i check the link but Page Not Found here